# Polling script in Linux machine which will notify arrival of new files on Windows shared folder

Tags: linux, windows, shared-folders, windows-subsystem-for-linux, smbclient

I am trying to write shell script in Linux server, which will notify the user about arrival of new file on Windows shared drive.

Most of the solutions suggests following approach:

1. Mount Windows shared folder on Linux
2. Enable polling through Linux shell scripting.

However I want to achieve this operation without mounting Windows drive on Linux, as mount operation is not allowed due to access issues.

Comment: This is not clear. Are you wanting to use Gnu/Linux or not? Where do you want to run this program?

Comment: We want to use Linux. Script will run in Linux machine and poll the windows shared folder.

Comment: How is it shared? Is it a network share? What is hosting the share? If it is a network share hosted in Gnu/Linux, then it is trivial, and can be done with little resources. If hosted on MS-Windows, then it may be better to put the monitoring there, as it has assess to change events.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
smbclient //server/share -A=/some/auth/file -TNc /some/timestamp/file - '/some/folder/*'
touch /some/timestamp/file
```

where:

- *//server/share* is your remote Windows share;
- */some/auth/file* is a file containing your credentials for accessing that share;
- */some/timestamp/file* is a file you use as a timestamp;
- */some/folder* is a folder on the remote share you want to find new files in;

The idea is that you consider any file on the remote share newer than this local */some/timestamp/file* as "new". If the cmbclient command receives anything other than 0 byte, you have new files. You may also pipe the standard output of the smbclient command to "`| tar tvf -`" to get a list of the new files.

The problem with this approach is that it actually *copies* all the new files' contents over. If you have large files on the remote share, that would be a huge waste of bandwidth. If the remote system has a command similar to the Linux `find`, you may run that instead of using `tar`.